# Probability density integration and expected cost

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

Here is my question:

[image: Probability Density Problem]

I've done the following:

1. Expected value of t = integral of t*f(t) = integral of te^-t from 0 to infinity
2. Integrated te^-t to get (-te^-t) - (e^-t) from 0 to infinity
3. Found the expected value of t to be 1 by evaluating the integral
4. Taken the square root of 1 to find the expected cost, with a final answer of 1

For some reason this doesn't seem right.. would someone be able to tell me if I'm going about this correctly? Any help would be much appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct because if the cost random variable $C$ is related to the time random variable $T$ by the formula $$C = g(T) = \sqrt{T},$$ then in general,  $$\operatorname{E}[g(T)] \ne g(\operatorname{E}[T]).$$  Instead, $$\operatorname{E}[g(T)] = \int_{t \in \Omega} g(t) f_T(t) \, dt,$$ where $\Omega$ is the support of $T$.  That is to say, $$\operatorname{E}[C] = \operatorname{E}[\sqrt{T}] = \int_{t=0}^\infty \sqrt{t} e^{-t} \, dt.$$  Evaluation of this integral requires the knowledge that $$\int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$